# How to save JSON objects in a array?`

Tags: php, json

First of all, here's the code I'm using

```
$json = file_get_contents('./releases.json');
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$region = isset($_GET['region']) ? $_GET['region'] : null;

# if region is not null: ?region=8
if ($region) {
    $region_filter = function($v) use ($region) {
        // 8 == Worldwide
        if ($v['region'] == $region || $v['region'] == 8) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    $data = array_filter($data['data'], $region_filter);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

As you can see I'm using array('data' => $data) to store my JSON objects ($data) in array named 'data', but all this do is create a parent object data that has all the other objects not an array, how can i fix this? Thank you very much!

releases.json example:

```
{
"last_update_on": "2017-12-30",
"data": [{..}, {..}]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the output you expect? What is the structure of releases.json?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question

Comment: Presume you want, `echo json_encode($data);`, else show your expected output.

Comment: Yes, but how you want to fix this? What structure would you expect?

Comment: What I want is {"data":[..]} with the new filtered data I get with ?region=

Comment: Thats what your getting, an array of the filtered objects.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone What I get from my code right now is : {"data":{"0":{"id":130427,"created_at":1512521776301,"updated_at":1512549188911, "region":8}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$_GET['region']` is not set, then you skip the code within the `if` block and so still has `$data['data']` in it and then you add another level with `array('data'=>$data)`.

But if `$_GET['region']` is set, then the code within the `if` block will remove the top level `'data'` it does `$data = array_filter($data['data'], $region_filter);`.

In other words, `$data` is structurally different depending on if the `if` block code is executed or not.  Try this

```
$json = file_get_contents('./releases.json');
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$data = $data['data'];
$region = isset($_GET['region']) ? $_GET['region'] : null;

# if region is not null: ?region=8
if ($region) {
    $region_filter = function($v) use ($region) {
        // 8 == Worldwide
        if ($v['region'] == $region || $v['region'] == 8) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    $data = array_filter($data, $region_filter);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```